# Creating conditional partials with ngIf

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I'm looking to implement an application wide nav and subnav combination with conditional logic that shows a sidenav on a specific page. I've tried a few of the ngIf on routerLink posts here, but none have solved my issue. 
app.component.html is my main container, header, and subnav, as described by the Clarity docs. 
app.component.html

```
<div class="main-container">
   <header class="header">
   </header>

   <nav class="subnav">
   </nav>

   <div class="content-container">
      <div class="content-area">
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>

      <nav *ngIf="router.url === '/page'" class="sidenav">
      </nav>
   </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
class PageComponent {
    constructor(public router: Router) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add code in `app.component.ts` whatever you tried?

Comment: it's the second code block

Comment: Alternatively you can add a combination of named routers with *ngIf or ngStyle or canActivate. It's definitely a choice of what is cleaner and your preference. I have used *ngIf for some menus items that need to be hidden if that is the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can have two different layouts in your application

1. Blank Layout   //it has no sidebar
2. Main Layout    //it has your sidebar

Your `router` will look like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
    path: '',
    component: BlankLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'logincustomer',pathMatch:'full' },
        { path: 'logincustomer', component: LoginComponent }
    ]
  },
{

    path: 'user',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
         { path: 'user', redirectTo:'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }]
 };
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Could I more simply arrive at this solution with *ngStyle using a display: none property?

Comment: @JonathonHambleton you can also do it using `ngStyle`, but the way shown above is very effective for large scale applications.